# Async await assignment

Tags: scala

I was looking over some Scala server code and I saw thins `async/await` block:

```
async {
  while (cancellationToken.nonCancelled) {
    val (request, exchange) = await(listener.nextRequest)
    respond(exchange, cancellationToken, handler(request))
  }
}
```

How can this be correct syntax?

As I understand it:

For every execution of the while loop

- Thread 1 will execute the code from the while loop except the one in the `await` clause.
- Thread 2 will go in the `await` clause.

But then Thread 1 will have `val (request, exchange)` uninstantiated in case Thread 2 doesn't finish computing.

These values will be passed to the `respond` and `handler` methods uninstantiated.

So how can you have an assignment in two different threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can you have an assignment in two different threads?

async-await's main goal is to allow you to do asynchronous programming in a synchronous fashion.

What really happens is that the awaited call executes `listener.nextRequest` and asynchronously waits for it's completion, *it doesn't execute the next line of code until then.* This guarantees that if the next line of code is executed, it's values are populated. The assignment should happen where it is visible to the next LOC in the method.

This is possible due to the fact that the `async` macro actually transforms this code into a state-machine, where the first part is the execution up until the first `await`, and the next part is everything after.